# Nontrivial Invariants of trilinear functionals

Tags: geometric-invariant-theory, multilinear-algebra

The group $\operatorname{SL}(n_1,\mathbb{C}) \times \operatorname{SL}(n_2,\mathbb{C}) \times \operatorname{SL}(n_3,\mathbb{C})$ acts on ${\mathbb C}^{n_1} \otimes {\mathbb C}^{n_2} \otimes {\mathbb C}^{n_3}$ in the obvious way. Is there an easy way to classify triples $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ for which this action has at least one nontrivial invariant? I don't need to explicitly *know* any invariants so long as they exist. This problem has unexpectedly arisen from a very concrete problem in analysis and I unfortunately don't know much GIT. I've consequently had little success trying to sort out what more abstract results might imply in this simple case. I'm also very much interested to know about the real version of this same question as well, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: The condition $n_1 \leq n_2 n_3$ and its cyclic permutations are necessary, as one can see by noting that any tensor spans a $\leq n_2n_3$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb C^{n_1}$ and considering a vector in $SL(n_1, \mathbb C)$ with a small eigenvalue on that subspace. I think this necessary condition is also sufficient but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Just from playing around with matrices, I'm fairly sure that $(2,n,m)$ for $2 < n < m$ only has an invariant when $n/m = k/(k+1)$ for some positive integer $k$.

Comment: Actually I think what I said is not right and a better condition is given by castling transforms. A nondegenerate tensor gives an $n_1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb C^{n_2} \otimes \mathbb C^{n_3}$, which is equivalent to a perpendicular $n_2n_3-n_1$-dimensional subspace of the dual $\mathbb C^{n_2} \otimes \mathbb C^{n_3}$.  I think you can transfer invariants from one to the other, so there is a nontrivial invariant for $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ if and only if there is one for $(n_2n_3-n_1,n_2,n_3)$.

Comment: One can apply this in each variable to either reduce to the case $n_1 \leq n_2n_3/2$, $n_2 \leq n_1 n_3/2$, $n_3 \leq n_1 n_2/2$ or to a boundary case where there clearly are or aren't invariants. If $2< n <m $ then you hit a case where there are invariants if the ratio is $k/(k+1)$ and a case where there are no invariants otherwise, so this checks out.